# Creating a webbrowser control in a background thread in backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

Is it possible to create a WebBrowser control in a background thread in BackgroundWorker?

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Using web1 As New WebBrowser

    End Using
End Sub
```

This throws the following error:

> ActiveX control
>   '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2'
>   cannot be instantiated because the
>   current thread is not in a
>   single-threaded apartment.

Does anyone know a way to create a background WebBrowser? I would like to do it to extract  info from websites then spit out the various HTML DOM arrays

Answer (score 1):

Set the appartment state of your thread before the thread is started:

```
myThread.IsBackground = false;
myThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
myThread.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The thread that the Webbrowser runs in must be [ApartmentState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.apartmentstate.aspx).STA. From a BackgroundWorker thread you'll have to use Invoke on a UI object and add the Webbrowser in that context.

I don't think you really need to run the WebBrowser object in a background thread anyway. All of it's functionality is handled asynchronously with events.

Comment: im not trying to add a webbrowser to the form, but load it as a class and use it's dom functions to extract info from a website, end goal is to ferry the htmldocument object to the backgroundworker result object

Comment: OK. Then instead of using BackgroundWorker, create a real thread and use the .SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA). That may work.

Comment: I've done a lot of this kind of work, and found huge grief trying to do anything at scale with this approach.  The WB control is just too flaky.  It crashes, shows modal dialogs, returns blank pages, and lots of other problems when automated in this way.  I went with downloading the raw html and parsing it with majestic (http://www.majestic12.co.uk/projects/html_parser.php).  This will probably be 1000 times faster and vastly more reliable in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a wrapper class, that instantiates the web browser control, create methods that wrap your extraction functions, and fire off the results through public events.

From here you just create a new instance of your wrapper, and add it to the ThreadPool.

Remember to do proper owner-thread invoking to avoid cross-thread exceptions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Having been down both roads, I would recommend [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/), an open source library to automate IE and Firefox. The WebBrowser control is good for displaying content, but for anything more complex it becomes a big hassle.

Comment: hmm not trying to display content only extract the dom elements with the jscript client side manipulation intact, for instance if the jscript alters a image on page load, i want the resulting HTML Document and dom structure which that i can manipulate in program, thinking i could escape using the webbrowser. i wasnt expecting to be slowed down by the threading issue

Comment: right now stuck on how do i make threads do something useful, as i dont understand the THREAD constructor right now, too used to backgroundworkers